# How to solve this quadratic optimization problem in R?

Tags: r, optimization, quadratic-programming, argmax

I am currently trying to implement a bigger simulation exercise but i'm stuck with this bit. 
The aim is to find the vector p* (2x1) that maximizes this function (p* = argmax of h):
[Equation](https://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=h(p%7CY%2Cq)%20%3D%20-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D(c-p)%5ET%20diag(%5B%5Cfrac%7Bq_1%7D%7Bc_1-s_1%7D%2C%5Cfrac%7Bq_2%7D%7Bc_2-s_2%7D%20%5D%5ET)(c-p)%0A%0A)
Also Y and q are given and all other quantities in the function are defined using them.

```
P_priority_i <- function(unknown, arg1, arg2, i){ 
mu = 2
delta = 0.00001
c <- c(pbar[i,] + rep(delta,m))
e <- rep(0,2)
s <- rep(0,2)
for (j in 1:m){ 
    e[j] <- x[i,j] + sum(A[[j]][i,]*min(pbar[i,j],arg1[i,j]))
}
if(y[i,'countries'] != 'IT'){ 
   s[1] <- min(pbar[i,1],(max(0,sum(arg2*e)))/arg2[1])
   s[2] <- min(pbar[i,2],(max(0,sum(arg2*e)-arg2[1]*s[1]))/arg2[2])
   value <- -0.5*t(c-unknown)%*%diag(arg2/(c-s))%*%(c-unknown)
return(value)
} else { 
   s[2] <- min(pbar[i,2],(max(0,sum(arg2*e)))/arg2[2])
   s[1] <- min(pbar[i,1],(max(0,sum(arg2*e)-arg2[2]*s[2]))/arg2[1])
   value <- -0.5*t(c-unknown)%*%diag(arg2/(c-s))%*%(c-unknown)
   return(value)
   }}
```

I've checked the formulation of the function, whose output is a scalar, and it is correct.

I also have 3 constraints on p*:

[Constraints](https://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=p%5E*%20%5Cge%200%20%5C%5C%0Ap%5E*%20%5Cle%20%5Cbar%7Bp%7D%5C%5C%0Aq%5ETp%5E*%20%5Cle%20q%5ETx%0A)
where \bar{p} and x are given quantities.

I've found quadprog package but I don't know how to solve this particular problem using solve.QP function () which supposes an objective function as (− d^T b + 0.5 b^T D b). The problem is that the argument of my maximization should be p and not (c-p) (also the constrains are formulated w.r.t p).

How can i set up this in R?

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Please include a sample of your data and the code you have tried, so you can help us help you. Have you had a chance to look at the guidance about how to ask a really good question [MRE]?

Comment: Your images are fully black when I click on the links.

Comment: I've fixed the images